# SQL Case when on various field, with varying data availibility

Tags: sql

this is my first ever question on here and I feel like it's such a stupid one, but I can't seem to get this right.

I have a table with 4x address lines [Addr1], [Addr2], [Addr3], [Addr4].

I need to query this data and rearrange it into 2x fields instead of 4, namely [City] and [Street]. These 4x fields were never completed properly or consistently on the UI, so the actual city could be in either Addr2, 3 or 4.

Now I have tried the below code, but I must be doing something wrong, because even when I do have no data in Addr4 and Addr3, I still do not get Addr2 in my new [City] field. I feel like the answer must be painfully obvious, but I'm still a rookie, so hoping someone would be ever so kind as to help me out?

```
        case when Addr4 = '' then Addr3
     when Addr4 = '' and Addr3 = '' then Addr2
     else Addr4
  end as City
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   select COALESCE(Addr4,Addr3,Addr2,Addr1) as City from table.
   -- or select NVL(Addr4,Addr3,Addr2,Addr1) as City from table.
```

May be the Values are NULL not blank .

Comment: Thanks  so much!  I tested it and the values are blank not NULL, but I completely forgot about COALESCE and how well it would work here, so I used NULLIF to change the values to NULL and wrapped that in the COALESCE and I'm getting exactly what I needed - thanks so much! :)  coalesce(nullif(Addr4, ''), nullif(Addr3, ''), nullif(Addr2, '')) as City
, Addr1 + ' ' + Addr2 as Street